# How to change columns and rows using asdoc

Tags: stata, panel, mean

I am trying to report descriptive stats in the paper.

As I am dealing with panel data, I need to report the mean and SD according to the year.

So I want years to be placed in the first row and the variables are in the first column.

```
bys wave: asdoc variable1 variable2,  replace stat(mean sd)
```

However, this code produces the opposite. How can I deal with this problem?
(I am using Stata 14)

Answer (score 0):

Try to interchange position of variable1 amd variable2

```
asdoc variable2 variable1, replace stat(mean sd)
```

Comment: What I want to do is to change the position of wave and variables, not the position between variables. The aforementioned code produces the table where wave is placed in an increasing order in the row, not in the column.